# JSX element type 'AddIcon' does not have any construct or call signatures when testing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have this code:

```
const tableIcons: Icons = {
  Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />)
};

const AddIcon = tableIcons.Add;

describe("tableIcons", () => {
  test("Render Add Icon as example", () => {
    const ref = React.createRef();
    render(<AddIcon ref={ref} />);
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

And I'm getting this error, any ideas what can cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `AddIcon` component should be `ForwardRefExoticComponent` generic type. See the return type of `forwardRef` function:

```
function forwardRef<T, P = {}>(render: ForwardRefRenderFunction<T, P>): ForwardRefExoticComponent<PropsWithoutRef<P> & RefAttributes<T>>;
```

An working example:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React, { forwardRef, ForwardRefExoticComponent } from 'react';

const AddBox = forwardRef((props, ref) => <div>AddBox</div>);
const Check = forwardRef(() => <span>Check</span>);

interface AddIconProps {}
interface CheckProps {}
interface Icons {
  Add: ForwardRefExoticComponent<AddIconProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLDivElement>>;
  Check: ForwardRefExoticComponent<CheckProps & React.RefAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>>;
}

const tableIcons: Icons = {
  Add: forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, AddIconProps>((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
  Check: forwardRef<HTMLSpanElement, CheckProps>((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
};

const AddIcon = tableIcons.Add;

describe('tableIcons', () => {
  test('Render Add Icon as example', () => {
    const ref = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>();
    render(<AddIcon ref={ref} />);
    screen.debug();
  });
});
```

package version:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. We forgot to mention that we are using material-UI icons and the material-table library, so we don't need to declare the types for our components. Do you think that we have to use custom types with ForwardRefExoticComponent as your example? I really appreciate any help you can provide. Pablo.